# How to write down a normal form of the game with information set?

Tags: game-theory

How can we write down a normal form for this following game with information set?

(The picture is modified from a picture from Wikipedia.)
[image]

Comment: A player cannot have different actions at different nodes of an information set. In particular, Player 2 cannot have {T,B} at the top node of his information set and {L,R} at the bottom node.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Would the current game work?

Comment: @HerrK. So the strategies to be included in the normal form is: Player 1: Up, Uq, Dp, Dq; 
Player 2: T, B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of the normal form game derived from an extensive form is given by the number of pure strategies each player has.

Generally speaking, the number of pure strategies a player has in an extensive form game equals the product of the number of actions at each information set where she moves. Suppose a player moves at $N$ information sets on a game tree, and at each information set $n$ there are $m_n$ actions, then she has $m_1\times m_2\times\cdots\times m_N$ number of pure strategies.

In your example, $N=2$, $m_1=m_2=2$ for player 1; and $N=1$, $m_1=2$ for player 2. So the normal form game corresponding to your game tree should be a $4\times2$ matrix.

[This note](http://www.sfu.ca/~shihenl/302/Strategies%20Memo.pdf) describes a step-by-step procedure that's relatively easy to follow.

Comment: The note lists the same steps that I do...

Comment: @Giskard: Yes, but with a little bit more detail `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.

Determine strategies.

Step 2.

Calculate payoffs for strategy profiles.

Step 3.

Write normal form.

Comment: Would it be the same as if the information set was not there? (I mean "as if the two nodes in the information set are in separate information set").

Comment: No. If you do not understand what strategies are, please consult your textbook.

Comment: I only know that their strategies are respectively: Player 1: Up, Uq, Dp, Dq; Player 2: TL, TR, BL, BR. Can you tell me my mistake?

Comment: Yes: your mistake is that these are not the strategies with imperfect information. Please consult your textbook.

Comment: Does it mean that I need to make assumption about belief before deriving the appropriate strategy?

Comment: Which textbook told you that? Please name your source (title and page number).